# perform calculations on values from csv

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a csv-file in the form of

```
100000000,0.0565325,-122.797,0.9984,-32.5345,0.9984,-32.5345,0.0565325,-122.271
101000000,0.0570362,-123.125,0.998372,-32.8592,0.998372,-32.8592,0.0570362,-122.593
102000000,0.0575381,-123.452,0.998343,-33.1838,0.998343,-33.1838,0.0575381,-122.915
103000000,0.0580382,-123.779,0.998314,-33.5085,0.998314,-33.5085,0.0580382,-123.237
```

and plot the data with `pgfplots`. However I want to 'manipulate' the values as

- divide the first column by $10^9$ (Hz->GHz)
- perform '20log(abs(x))' as x is given in linear form and needs to be plotted in dB.

I have found 4 occurences of `calc` in the pgfplots documentary but that cases do not deal with read information.

[image: This is what I want to achieve (without grey bg)]

[image: This is what I currently have. The alignment will be fixed]

I am aware that the plots do not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! You can use the options `x expr` and `y expr` to perform calculations on the data that is read from a table (from a file or inline).

If your data has no column names, you can use `\thisrowno` to access the data in the relevant column (`\thisrowno{0}` depicting the first column). If the columns have names, you can access the data in the relevant data using `\thisrow{<column name>}`.

So, for example you could write `y expr={20*log10(abs(\thisrowno{1}))}` to apply 20 log(abs(x)) on the value of the second column of your CSV data.

I am unsure whether the following is what you're after as you did not provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), but it might at least get you started:

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
100000000,0.0565325,-122.797,0.9984,-32.5345,0.9984,-32.5345,0.0565325,-122.271
101000000,0.0570362,-123.125,0.998372,-32.8592,0.998372,-32.8592,0.0570362,-122.593
102000000,0.0575381,-123.452,0.998343,-33.1838,0.998343,-33.1838,0.0575381,-122.915
103000000,0.0580382,-123.779,0.998314,-33.5085,0.998314,-33.5085,0.0580382,-123.237
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, header=false]{data.csv}\datatable

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={GHz}, 
            ylabel={dB},
            xtick=data, 
            x tick label style={
                /pgf/number format/precision=3,
                /pgf/number format/fixed,
                /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill
            }
        ]  
        \addplot table[
            x expr={\thisrowno{0}/1e9}, 
            y expr={20*log10(abs(\thisrowno{1}))}
        ] {\datatable};
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]